# remove some top, down rows and right, and left some columns of jpg image border using matlab

Tags: matlab, border

I have RGB museum JPG Images. most of them have image footnotes on one or more sides, and I'd like to remove them. I do that manually using paint software. now I applied the following matlab code to remove the image footnotes automatically. I get a good result for some images but for others it not remove any border. Please, can any one help me by update this code to apply it for all images?

```
 'rgbIm = im2double(imread('A3.JPG')); 
          hsv=rgb2hsv(rgbIm);
          m = hsv(:,:,2);
          foreground = m > 0.06; % value of background
           foreground = bwareaopen(foreground, 1000); % or whatever.
            labeledImage = bwlabel(foreground);
            measurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'BoundingBox');
            ww = measurements.BoundingBox;
             croppedImage = imcrop(rgbImage, ww);'
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What problems are you facing?

Comment: I have museum image database with (jpg) format, each image has border and I should remove this border because it is out of the original image.

Comment: I like to show some example of museum image but I didn't know how can I do that

Comment: Please, can you tell me how can I upload the image here?

Comment: @zenab - When you're editing the question, there is a button in the toolbar that allows you to upload images.  Use that to upload them.

Comment: @ rayryeng..thank you, But when I upload the original image (with frames) I get this message " For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames".

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the boundaries you could use "imclearborder", where it checks for labelled components at boundaries and clears them. Caution! if the ROI touches the boundary, it may remove. To avoid such instance you can use "imerode" with desired "strel" -( a line or disc) before clearing the borders. The accuracy or generalizing the method to work for all images depends entirely on "threshold" which separates the foreground and background.

More generic method could be - try to extract the properties of footnotes. For instance, If they are just some texts, you can easily remove them by using a edge detection and morphology opening with line structuring element along the cols. (basic property for text detection)

Hope it helps.

I could give you a clear idea or method if you upload the image.

Comment: thanks for reply ..I can upload the image but it upload without frame that happened when I upload last time. If you can give your email I can send you some examples from my images database.

Comment: thanks for reply ..I can upload the image but it upload without frame that happened when I upload last time. If you can give your email I can send you some examples from my images database. –